# Detect when delete key pressed on control

Tags: swift, macos, nscontrol

How can I subclass a `NSControl` object (such as a `NSImageView`) to detect the press of the delete key? Specifically I want to clear an image from a `NSImageView`, but there are probably wider applications.

Answer (score 7):

Subclass the `NSControl` and override the `keyDown` function. Use NSEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers to check against the unicode value of `NSDeleteCharacter`.

```
    override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        //From Apple sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Swift_ListerOSX_ListViewController_swift.html
        if theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers == String(Character(UnicodeScalar(NSDeleteCharacter))) {
            //Take action. 

        }
     }
```

Comment: For me, just `event.charactersIgnoringModifiers == String(UnicodeScalar(NSDeleteCharacter)!)` works. I am using Swift 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

It should work to just implement the `-delete:` action method, which is what the Delete item of the Edit menu sends to the responder chain. That way, it works not just for the Delete key but for all other ways of invoking that menu item (mouse, putting focus on the menus and navigating by arrow keys, accessibility technologies, etc.).

In fact, `NSImageView` already implements `-delete:`, so are you sure you have to do anything?

Comment: Wow - this sounds much better. I can't override any method called delete, but there is a `deleteBackward`. The app is based around a `NSStatusBarWindow` with no dock icon, so we don't actually implement a edit menu at the moment - is this a requirement?

Comment: Well, if you don't already have an Edit menu, then this approach is probably not any easier than others. You could arrange to provide such a (perhaps hidden) menu, but it ends up being more complicated.

Comment: This is a great answer just not applicable in my case.